# NuGet update_package in entire solution

Tags: nuget

Maybe I am missing something very simple but how do you update a package in multiple projects in a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Old question, but for those that are interested, works out of the box now with the ['Update-Package' command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console#updating-a-package) in the Package Manager Console

Comment: The new URL is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console#updating-a-package

Answer (score 5):

Install 
http://nuget.org/List/Packages/NuGetPackageUpdater

```
PM> Install-Package NuGetPackageUpdater
```

Then just type (in the command console, while the solution in question is opened)

```
PM> Update-Package
```

Otherwise there's currently a workitem to bake this functionality directly into NuGet with something like an Update-Package -all flag.
Ref: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/431

Comment: I did the Install/Update above and it worked. A coworker did it and it blew up. So YMMV.

Comment: NuGetPackageUpdater is deprecated in Nuget 1.4. I read that workitem, but couldn't decide if it had actually been implemented.

Answer (score 4):

You can now "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ..." when you right-click the project.

Answer (score 2):

Currently in 1.3 there is no way to do this. This feature will be in 1.4 please see: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/431 If you would like to preview this feature you can install a build form out CI machine see: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget#Installing_a_CI_build